# Software for topographer on Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: linux

I am a topographer freshly come out from school, I have worked a while during all my career in a software called COVADIS+AUTOCAD in combination for editing geobase and make skretch. Can somebody please tell me if i can move on Ubuntu/Linux to accomplish the same things

Comment: This is the correct site to ask your question, but you should be aware of https://gis.stackexchange.com/ which might be of interest to you.